# FlutterFire - Working with Functions emulator and actual android device

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am working in a flutter project and using my personal device for debugging. added, I need to use functions emulator for firebase, but i am keep getting **functions unavailable** error in flutter, when i try to call my function via emulator.

What I have...
firebase.json

```
"emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "host" : "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "host" : "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 5001
    },}
```

in main.dart

```
FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator("172.20.10.7", 5001); // my system ip in local network
```

in pubspec.yaml

```
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.6
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.7
  cloud_functions: ^3.2.7
  firebase_database: ^9.0.6
```

where 172.20.10.7 => this is my system ip in local network..

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, I don't know what should I do to overcome this.

Comment: Is your device connected to the computer that runs the emulator via a cable, or they are just on the same network?

Comment: @PeterKoltai, Thanks for the reply, They are on the same network as well as the device is connected via USB.

Comment: Do you recall if you ever fixed this, @VetriveluMurugesan? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @BrysonThill, I am not familiar, but please try this, use the "firebase serve" command, instead of "emulators".